# (ASP.NET) In grid view, how can I make the selected row data show up on a confirmation dialog box?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, selected, linkbutton, onclientclick

I tried the following code on a `linkbutton onClientClick`. But it is calling an error.

```
return confirm('""Are you sure you want to report on the  & **row.Cells(3).Text** &  vs  & **row.Cells(4).Text** & game, at the  & **row.Cells(5).Text** &  stadium. For  & **row.Cells(2).Text** &  on the  & **row.Cells(1).Text &** " ."');
```

Below is the rest of the code.

```
<asp:gridview id="FixtureGridView" runat="server"
              autogeneratecolumns="False"
              datasourceid="matches"
              height="140px" 
              width="800px" 
              onselectedindexchanged="FixtureGridView_SelectedIndexChanged">
              <columns>
                  <asp:commandfield showselectbutton="True" />
                  <asp:boundfield datafield="date" headertext="date" sortexpression="date" readonly="True" />
                  <asp:boundfield datafield="kick-off time" headertext="kick-off time" sortexpression="kick-off time" />
                  <asp:boundfield datafield="home team" headertext="home team" sortexpression="home team" />
                  <asp:boundfield datafield="away team" headertext="away team" sortexpression="away team" />
                  <asp:boundfield datafield="stadium" headertext="stadium" sortexpression="stadium" />
                  <asp:TemplateField>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Runat="server"
                                          OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to report on this game');"
                                          CommandName="Select">
                          Report
                          </asp:LinkButton>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: You must me doing something else on codebehind. It's impossible to get that error message from the markup you just posted.

Comment: @Icarus Ye I have tried to post something in the codebehind but I cannot seem to get a dialog box up unless I use JQuery. But I do not know how to implement it or call the function in the codebehind

Comment: look at James' answer; that's how you should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the row_databound event of the gridview like this, you have to cast the found control to the same control type

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
    LinkButton link = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton1");
    link.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure you want to report on this game');");
}
```

Comment: Thank You, this worked great. Altered the code to the following.

Comment: if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                String Message = "Are you sure you want to report on the " + e.Row.Cells[2].Text + " VS. " + e.Row.Cells[3].Text + " game, at the " + e.Row.Cells[4].Text + " stadium. At " + e.Row.Cells[1].Text + " on the " + e.Row.Cells[0].Text + ".";
                LinkButton link = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("ReportLinkButton"); 
                
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('" + Message + "')");

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to build the confirmation using the `Eval` function:

```
<asp:Button OnClientClick="return confirm('<%# String.Format("Delete {0}?", Eval("SomeColumn")) %>');" />
```

Comment: What's there to elaborate on? Just build your confirmation like demonstrated in my example. Is there something about the example that's confusing you?

Comment: Basically it is throwing an error, and the button is not click-able, since the error is that it cannot runat server. I will look more into understanding eval function, thank you.